# XMonad (or xmonad-contrib) function to read current layout name?

Tags: xmonad, xmonad-contrib

Say I have an XMonad layout that I named `"foo"` via [`XMonad.Layout.Renamed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.12/docs/XMonad-Layout-Renamed.html).

I've got a keybinding that I would like bound to a different `X ()` depending on the current layout of the focused workspace. For example, something along the lines of:

```
case () of
() | currentLayoutName == "foo" -> fooAction
   | otherwise                  -> barAction
```

..but how can I implement `currentLayoutName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just traverse down the StackSet to the current workspace to the layout description.

```hs
-- Imports
…
import qualified XMonad.StackSet as W
…

-- Key bindings
…
, ((modm, xK_F1), do
    wset <- gets windowset
    let ldesc = description . W.layout . W.workspace . W.current $ wset
    case ldesc of
        "foo" -> fooAction
        _     -> barAction
  )
…
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I did not understand how `StackSet` was structured well enough, but this cleared it right up for me.